# How can I stop my program after the execution of the promises from XMLHttp answer

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I’m trying to convert an Image to a String and after this I want to test the string to see if it exist in my database. To do this I use open cv, the conversion from image to string work well every third time I have the good string named licence. Then I have a problem with my function testerLicence. I do a XMLHttp request in which I send the licence to a php file who connect the database and test if the licence exist. This function take time to finish, so I put a promise inside to return a Boolean.
In my main program I have a loop that is read until the license is true. I never get out of my loop even when the license is true I think the problem comes from the promise but I failed to find

```
This is my main program with a loop, process image and licence test
boutonPhoto.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var endLoop = false;
  while (endLoop!=true) {
    try {
     Process image to String uneLicence
        testerLicence(uneLicence).then((boolIfExist) => {console.log(boolIfExist); endLoop = boolIfExist });;
      }
    }
    catch (e) {
      //If there is an erros with the process o image then sortie = false
      endLoop = false;
    }
  }
```

This is my function testerLicence with XMLrequest

```
function testerLicence(numLicence) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Crée un nouvel objet XMLHttpRequest
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Définit l'URL du fichier PHP à appeler
    const url = '../php/api.php';

    // Définit la méthode HTTP à utiliser (POST dans ce cas)
    xhr.open('POST', url);

    // Définit les en-têtes de la requête
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // Définit les données à envoyer au fichier PHP
    const data = 'license=' + numLicence.getNumLicence();

    console.log(data)
    // Envoie la requête
    xhr.send(data);

    // Traite la réponse
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        // Parse la réponse en tant que JSON
        const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        // Vérifie si la licence existe
        if (response.licenseExists) {
          // La licence existe
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          // La licence n'existe pas
          resolve(false);
        }
      }
    };
  });
}
```

This is php file who print in a json to send answer

```
<?php
// Récupération du numéro de licence dans les données de la requête
$license = $_POST['license'];

// Requête à la base de données pour vérifier si le numéro de licence existe
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_sporttrack;charset=utf8','root','root');
$req = "SELECT * FROM Joueur WHERE licence = :licence";
$req = $conn->prepare($req);
$req->execute(['licence'=>$license]);
$res = $req->fetchAll();

// Vérification si le numéro de licence existe
if (count($res) > 0) {
  // Le numéro de licence existe
  $response = ['licenseExists' => true];
} else {
  // Le numéro de licence n'existe pas
  $response = ['licenseExists' => false];
}

// Retourne la réponse sous forme d'objet JSON
print(json_encode($response)); ?>
```

If someone can help me to improve my program and to solve my problem

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: You could look into using async/await to simplify the code